# Wildfly 10 Consumes a lot of Memory

Tags: memory, wildfly, wildfly-10

I deploy 4 different war in a clustered environment on Wildfly 10 and Wildfly consumes a lot of memory.

My configuration on standalone.conf is;

```
...
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1400m -XX:MetaspaceSize=128M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=320m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
...
```

After Wildfly started, it takes 1.7 GB of memory and it increases to 1.8 GB in a short time.

Why Wildfly starts with using so much memory?

What is the reason of this and how can I prevent from this situation.

Comment: Are you using SSL or have you analyzed the memory?

Comment: I don't understand your concern.  You're giving it 1.4GB in the command line (-Xmx1400m) for just the heap.  In general, Java will fill all available memory given to it.  If you want it to take less then reduce the Xmx argument.

Comment: I want in to start from 256m and if necessary I want it to use 1.4g.

Comment: The JVM might decide to use the full 1.4G heap if you start an application and might shrink if it is not longer used later. But this is nothing you have a hand on beside the memory and GC options